# Microsoft word wont let me use shift8 to create a bullet point

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, autocorrect

Hello any help would be appreciated. I have not changed or edited any settings in Word yet * no longer makes a bullet point. I've tried Auto Correct in options and triggering automatic bullet lists and number lists (which were already on, yet not working) and restarting word but to no avail. The shortcut doesn't work in power point either and is driving me insane.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  To get you the best answer, please Edit your question (to the bottom left of the text).  Please indicate the precise version of Office, the precise OS, and whether or not Shift-8 creates the * in Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to trigger the creation of a bulleted list by typing an asterisk, please check your settings under Preferences to make sure they are correct. Under Preferences, you should go to AutoCorrect, then go to AutoFormat As You Type, check the box that says "Automatically correct spelling and formatting as you type," and then, under Replace As You Type, check the Automatic Bulleted Lists box. Thus:
[image]
After you do that, if you type an asterisk and then press either the space key or the tab key, Word should automatically convert the asterisk into a bullet and indent it (because the people at Microsoft want bulleted lists to be indented). It works perfectly on my copy of Word 365, which is version 16.25 (19050200).